# Size of a row different from the others row's

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I need to create a table with custom cell's, which have different size (Height).
Can i change the size of a row just from one or two cell??
Any idea how??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a mutable array that contains the heights of all of your rows, if you've got multiple sections, you can put multiple arrays inside a mutable array. let's say you've got 2 sections and 2 rows for each, then give your table view controller a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *heightData;
```

in the .m file:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)heightData
{
    if(nil == heightData)
    {
        heightData = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];

        //various heights for your different rows in different sections:
        NSMutableArray *sectionArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44]];
        NSMutableArray *sectionArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44]];

        [heightData addObject:sectionArray1];
        [heightData addObject:sectionArray2];
    }

    return heightData;
}
```

then, in your table view controller .m file, there's a protocol method that we must make use of, you can implement it like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *rowArray = [self.heightData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSNumber *height = [rowArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return [height floatValue];
}
```

the final step: when you want to change a height for a row, let's say it's the row in section 1, row 0, then you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *rowArray = [self.heightData objectAtIndex:1];
[rowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:55]];\\a new data
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

then the table view's going to resize the row with a smooth animation, you can explicitly resize and re-layout the views inside the row, but I don't recommend that, the table view'll automatically do this for you if you've got a custom-xib cell and the autoresizing settings are set properly

Answer (score 1):

Use [heightForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) from the UITableViewDelegate Protocol.